# Access web server on Windows computer from Mac on browser which are on same Network

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, mac, browser, apache-http-server

I have a laptop with Apache installed on Windows 10

I have another laptop with Mac installed, both are connected to same Wifi network.

I want to access Web Server of Windows from Mac's browser.

When I try to enter IP of my Windows computer in Mac, browser just keeps loading and loading.

When I do `ping x.x.x.x` in Mac's terminal it successfully receives packets.

**PS:**
I have iPhone 6, I can successfully access the Windows web server from my iPhone's Safari browser.

Comment: Do you have a firewall enabled on the Windows computer that's blocking access to port 80? For testing purposes, disable the firewall and see if the problem is resolved.

Comment: @Twisty tried to disable firewall but have no affect ... error in browser `This site cant' be reached`

Comment: Can you reach it from the Windows machine via `http:\\localhost`

Comment: @Twisty Yes, as i said, I can access `http:\\localhost` from my Windows (thats where server is installed) .. and can access via IP from iPhone ...

Comment: Do you have a proxy configured on the Mac?

Comment: @Twisty Nope ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56792/discussion-between-umair-and-twisty).